# Logging framework for mixed C#, managed C++, and unmanaged C++ application

Tags: c#, .net, c++, logging

**Specific Background:** I have a Word Add-In written in C#. This Add-In calls a plugin developed for another application (EndNote) written in C++, which is further divided into managed and unmanaged code. The C# code is run from one process, while the C++ code is run from another. Furthermore, the C++ code is multithreaded.

I've been considering using either one of or a combination of the following, but am open to other suggestions:

- log4net
- log4cxx
- nlog
- System.Diagnostics.Trace
- System.Diagnostics.TraceSource

What would you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pick a framework for C# and one for C++ (have you consider log4cplus?) and decide which one can be easily adapted so that its log output is written to the other framework. Which one to pick depends on the structure of your code ("who knows whom?").

Comment: The application written in C++ self-hosts a WCF service that the C# application can call. However, the C# application has use-cases that exist independently of the C++ one. Also, the C++ app has a small bit that executes when the host application (Endnote) starts up or shuts down, but otherwise, only runs when called.

Comment: @Nathan - Sounds like there is nothing that you need to log within the C++ application that you cannot log from the C# application.

Comment: I think I need to at least log errors that occur within the C++ app, but that can't be propagated to the c# app. For example, if hosting the WCF service failed, I wouldn't be able to log much useful information unless the C++ app also does some logging.

Also, if there is an exception calling the service due to a failure of the host, how would I log it? I see a benefit to having all the logging handled in one place, but I feel that I would need some additional logging. I could write a temp log and remove it when a transaction is complete, but then where's the benefit of centralized logging?